# How to enable edit-mode on a specific cell in a QTableWidget?

Tags: qt, cell, editing, qtablewidget

I can go to a specific cell:

```
ui->tableWidget->setCurrentCell(ui->tableWidget->rowCount() - 1, 0);
```

But how do I put the cell into editor mode, so the user does not have to double click the cell to begin editing the contents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `QTableWidget` class inherits [`QAbstractItemView`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html), which has the required APIs.

You just need to get the relevant model index using [currentIndex()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#currentIndex), and then pass that to the [edit()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#edit) slot to put the current cell into edit-mode:

```
ui->tableWidget->edit(ui->tableWidget->currentIndex());
```

Comment: I get a compilation error: no matching function for call to 'QTableWidget::edit(QTableWidgetItem*)'

Comment: @tyebillion. You need to use current**Index**, not currentItem.

Answer (score 0):

You can grap a `QTableWidgetItem` from the selection you made, and pass it to `QTableWidget::editItem(QTableWidgetItem)`;

```
ui->tableWidget->editItem(ui->tableWidget->currentItem());
```

Comment: This code compiles but (added to my code) doesn't do anything at run time.

Comment: @tyebillion For sure it works, if you add it after you set the current cell.

Comment: @tyebillion I suppose you added `#include <QTableWidgetItem>` to your code?

Comment: Well your code compiles, so why do I need to include anything more? The cell is highlighted by my code, but pressing keys on the keyboard does not edit the cell.

Comment: @tyebillion, For testing I put the code by the end of constructor, when application opens, the cell is highlighted and in edit mode (content highlighted and blinking)

Comment: I tested also with a signal / slot  and it works too.

Comment: I'm not getting that behaviour. I'm running on Linux Mint. Have you changed any of the properties on the QTableWidget?

Comment: @tyebillion, No I only made simple test on Windows without changes